# cursors WITH HOLD in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, cursors

Does Postgres allow to create cursors with option WITH HOLD using plpgsql? 
I want something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS refcursor 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$ 
DECLARE
    ref refcursor WITH HOLD;
BEGIN
    OPEN refcur FOR 
        SELECT some_data FROM some_table 
    RETURN ref;
END;
$$;
```

The more common problem is to find a way to use Postgres's cursors out of a transaction block. But cursor should be created automatically without name specification.

Comment: What is `WITH HOLD`? And why do you return a refcursor and not simply the query result (and declare the function as `returns table (...)`)

Comment: WITH HOLD is an option of explicit declaration of a cursor.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-declare.html
It's the easiest way to return a value of a single column of known type. Why one should return the whole table when one need only a column?

Comment: I've found a temporary decision for my problem here:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52968/how-can-i-keep-a-result-set-without-keeping-the-transaction-open